# How to replace [ ] in an array with a var result in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

How do I get the `var number = 33;` to be placed into [] in `{helloBean.day1WeatherType[]}` before it is placed onto my page?

```
var number = 33;
document.write("<h2><h:outputText  value=\"#{helloBean.day1WeatherTyp[number]}\" /></h2>");
```

I don't want to push the number into the array; I want to read that place in the array so array[33], but I need to be able to change it and not have it as a set number which.

Comment: There seems to be a fundamental misunderstanding about how server-side and client-side code works. You can't manipulate JSF code using JavaScript like this; Java has already rendered the page long ago so it's way too late to change anything in JS. You'll have to take some other approach to this.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that I understand the question, but maybe you asking for:

```
var number = 33;
document.write('<h2><h:outputText  value=\"#{helloBean.day1WeatherTyp[' + number + ']}\" /></h2>');
```

Comment: yes that's what I want, but that doesn't work sadly, I had already tried that. thanks

Answer (score -1):

Normally a regular expression can take care of this:

```
document.write("...".replace(/\[number\]/, number));
```